# Ubuntu, error 'cound't resolve host' when from curlftpfs fstab

Tags: ubuntu, fstab

I have problem with curlftpfs. When i mount it manualy everything works, but when I try to autmount via /etc/fstab, after reboot system stops on error 'Couldn't resolve host `[my host name]`.

Line I added to fstab:

```
curlftpfs#[username with @ escaped to %40]:[password]@[host] /media/[my dir] fuse allow_other,uid=0,gid=0 0 0
```

Manual command, that works:

```
curlftpfs [same username]:[same pass]@[same host] /media[same dir]
```

Comment: Did you try using IP instead of hostname in fstab entry?

Comment: Same error occurs. Couldn't resolve [host domain]. Not ip - but domain is mentioned as before. Does this maybe occur because of the @ in username? I can't get a username without this character...

Comment: No - that is not the problem. I tried with diffrent ftp, without @ in username. This is a server in cloud, maybe this has something to do with netowrking at the time fstab launches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `_netdev` requires network to be available before the mount. This is why your manual mount always works, but during a reboot the network has to be available before trying to mount a remote host.

Try this

```
curlftpfs#[username]:[password]@[host] /media/[my dir] fuse allow_other,uid=0,gid=0,_netdev 0 0
```